# SSIS heavy data import on Prod DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, import-from-csv

I need to import large amount of data around 1Mil rows from a CSV into my Prod DB table.
My table has around 50 Mil rows, 20 columns(int, decimal cols), 6 indexes.
What is the best approach to import this data using SSIS without taking down my DB or table?
I will be importing this kind of data biweekly using the SSIS package, so the amount of data after a few months will be increasing in the table which could affect the import process.

Comment: This depends on many factors.  Your best off by doing the leg work yourself and if you have any specific questions on the research you are doing post in the DBA exchange.

Comment: Is the table partitioned? Then you could switch out the partition, merge it with the new data and switch it in again.

Comment: No, the data table is not partitioned but we are considering it. Anyway new data could span multiple partitions. Do you suggest switch out and in multiple partitions? Would there be any downtime considering all the indexes?